# How to set environment variables in python when using vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

In vscode I have a project structure (using Windows):

- venv
- .env
- test_load_env.py

My .env file contains:

```
PYTHONPATH=.
MY_USERNAME=myusername
MY_PASSWORD=mypass
```

test_load_env.py:

```
import os

username = os.environ.get("MY_USERNAME")
password = os.environ.get("MY_PASSWORD")
print(f"username: {username}, password: {password}")
print(os.environ.get("PYTHONPATH"))
```

Using vscode 1.84.2 the .env file is not imported automatically as running test_load_env.py returns:

```
username: None, password: None
None
```

Adding

```
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
```

to settings.json makes no difference.  However, if I run as Debug Python File, then the environment variables are loaded correctly (even without the settings.json edit).

If I run the exact same project on vscode insiders (1.85.0), the environment variables are loaded correctly (without having to run as debug or edit settings.json).

My settings are identical between vscode and vscode insiders - why does vscode insiders import the environment variables as expected, but vscode doesn't?

Is my only solution under the release version of vscode is to use python-dotenv?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to use .env, why aren't you using the `dotenv` module?  Python doesn't load `.env` by default, and you shouldn't be relying on your editor to do it, because it won't be involved if you try to run from a command line.

Comment: Because https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file states: 
By default, the Python extension looks for and loads a file named .env in the current workspace folder, then applies those definitions. The file is identified by the default entry "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env" in your user settings
When running in a production environment, the the script will still read the environment variables - e.g. print(os.environ.get("windir")) works fine

Comment: That just confirms what I said.  In a production environment, it will get the environment variables.  It will NOT get the `.env` file.

Comment: Fine, but .env is the suggested way of setting the project folder to the pythonpath.  If vscode doesn't read .env, then that documented approach doesn't work.  If the correct way to import from a .env file in vscode is to use python-dotenv then fine, but that isnt what the documentation says, and the behaviour is inconsistent.

Comment: how exactly are you running? launch config? run button at top right? writing commands in integrated terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this has been an issue in vscode for a while:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/944

I think the solution is to add:

```
"python.experiments.optInto": ["pythonTerminalEnvVarActivation"]
```

into the user settings.json

.env then gets loaded by vscode when running code (not just debug).

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: Hi RA-LBR, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use debug mode or interactive window which will read `.env` file.

You can refer to this table about using `.env` and `launch.json` settings:

| Run option | .env setting | launch.json setting |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Run Python file in terminal | no | no |
| Run in interactive Window | yes | no |
| Debug via F5 | yes | yes |
| "Debug Python File" (*) | yes | no |

You can also [read document for more details about environment variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variables).

Answer (score 0):

```py
from decouple import config

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    ...
    JWT_SECRET_KEY: str = config("JWT_SECRET_KEY", cast=str)
    ...
```

No configuration needed.